# Merging Lists with a PushbackIterator?

Tags: java, merge, iterator

I have to use a `PushbackIterator` which uses a `pushback(E)` method.

So if the value in `aIter` is less than the value in `bIter`, `aIter` is returned, while the value in `bIter` is put into the `pushback(E)` method, and vice versa.

If the original lists are

> (1, 4, 5) and (2, 3, 6)

then the result list would be

> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

.

I believe that I need to determine if an iterator has no values left. So if bIter has no more elements, I get an element from aIter and add it to the result list.

How would I determine if an iterator has no more values?

```
public static<E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> mergeSortedLists(List<E> a, List<E> b) {
    List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();

    PushbackIterator<E> aIter = new PushbackIterator<E>(a.iterator());
    PushbackIterator<E> bIter = new PushbackIterator<E>(b.iterator());

    while (aIter.hasNext() && bIter.hasNext()) {
        if (aIter.next().compareTo(bIter.next()) < 0) {
            result.add(aIter.next());
            aIter.pushback(bIter.next());
        } 
        if (aIter.next().compareTo(bIter.next()) > 0)
            result.add(bIter.next());
            bIter.pushback(aIter.next());
        }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` terminates if one of the iterators has no more elements, thus afterwards you can just add the remaining elements of the iterators:

```
while (aIter.hasNext()) {
    result.add(aIter.next());
}
while (bIter.hasNext()) {
    result.add(bIter.next());
}
```

Btw, your code has some flaws since you call `.next()` multiple times before adding an element. Because of this you will skip elements. Try this:

```
public static<E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> mergeSortedLists(List<E> a, List<E> b) {
    List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();

    PushbackIterator<E> aIter = new PushbackIterator<E>(a.iterator());
    PushbackIterator<E> bIter = new PushbackIterator<E>(b.iterator());

    while (aIter.hasNext() && bIter.hasNext()) {
        E aElem = aIter.next();
        E bElem = bIter.next();
        if (aElem.compareTo(bElem) <= 0) {
            result.add(aElem);
            bIter.pushback(bElem);
        } else {
            result.add(bElem);
            aIter.pushback(aElem);
        }
    }

    while (aIter.hasNext()) {
        result.add(aIter.next());
    }
    while (bIter.hasNext()) {
        result.add(bIter.next());
    }

    return result;
}
```